# iOS: Maintain status bar after custom modal presentation

Tags: ios, statusbar, presentviewcontroller

I have a somewhat complex modal view controller hierarchy that is breaking the status bar in my iOS app.

My main view controller hierarchy is a `UINavigationController` subclass inside of a container `UIViewController`. When I enter into a Settings panel, I use a "card-like" animation to "shrink" the contained `UINavigationController` and then display the Settings panel `UIViewController` modally on top of the main `UINavigationController`. So far, so good. If I reverse that animation (exiting the Settings panel), my UI is restored as expected.

There is a function in the Settings panel, however, where another modal `UIViewController` (a custom `UIAlertView`-like modal) is displayed on top of the first modal `UIViewController`. When this happens, all is displayed as expected, but with one exception (detailed below, after some additional details):

- Prior to any of these animations, the contained `UINavigationController` has a `UINavigationBar` with a height of 64 points (44 points for the `UINavigationBar` and 20 points for the portion that extends under the status bar). This is correct.
- When the first animation occurs (presenting the "card-like" Settings panel), the 20 points of extra height are maintained, as they should be (this allows the unwinding of the UI to restore the original layout correctly).
- When the second animation occurs, presenting a modal `UIViewController` on top of the modal `UINavigationController`, the "extra" 20 points are animated away, and they do not return. This means that, when my animations are unwound, the `UINavigationBar` of my contained `UINavigationController` isn't tall enough, and its icons are displayed under the status bar icons.

I do not know why this change only happens when the second modal is presented. How can I keep that "extra" 20 points of padding all the time? If I can't do that, how can I restore it when needed?